# Finding the homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $F=\mathbb{Z_5}$, a finite field consists $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. Find an homogeneous system such that it's solutions spanned by $B=\{(1,2,3), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)\}$.

What I've done:
We're looking for $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ spanned by $B$.

Hence,
$x_1(1,2,3) + x_2(1,1,0) + x_3(1,1,1) = (x_1+x_2+x_3,2x_1+x_2+x_3,3x_1+x_3)$

What should I do next?
I understand I need to find an $A$ satisfying $Ax=0$, but how?

Comment: What do you mean by homogeneous system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \end{bmatrix}=-1 \neq 0
$$
in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, the vectors $(1,2,3)$, $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,1)$ are linearly independent.  Thus, $\mathrm{span}(B)=(\mathbb{Z}_5)^3$.

Thus, your task is to find a matrix $A$ such that $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathrm{span}(B)$ [i.e., for all $\mathbf{x} \in (\mathbb{Z}_5)^3$].  (The important bit here is the "for all".)

Comment: Oh, so that's why the only matrix solving the equation is the null matrix?